# android how to set a view on top of button without causing gray background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to implement a layout where I have ImageView and TextView on top of a Button.

target:
[image: my target]

I tried to use "android:elevation" or "android:translationZ" to achieve this, but the result is really disappointing, the view can be on top, but it will also have a gray background which I don't know how to get rid of.

what I get: [image: result]

Tried using "android:background="@android:color/transparent"", but it didn't work.

My Layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/table_page_turn_item_height">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/turn_btn_voice"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/table_page_turn_btn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/table_page_turn_btn_height"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/turn_text_name"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center"       
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_generic_light_blue_fill" 
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/turn_play_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_24px"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/turn_play_icon"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorEugraBlue"
    android:text="1:30"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_ctrl_large"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks!

Edit: tried to set the elevation to 1, then the ImageView will still hide behind the Button, only leaves a gray border..

The left gray square is the view which elevation is 1
[image: Elevation 1]

Comment: It seems any view iwth a elevator will appear to have gray background at Android Studio's Preview panel, I'll test more on emulator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's actually not a question, the stuff from Android Studio Preview panel was confusing, any View with elevation higher than 1 will be given a gray background, but it would be actually fine on emulator.

And for this specific case, I set elevation to 5, got the desired layout. elevation lower or equal to 2 will hide the view behind the button.

So I assume the button will have a elevation of 2 by default.

Answer (score 2):

The `Button` has a higher elevation than the other two views. For `ImageView`, it's exactly `1dp` higher. Hence, just set the ImageView's elevation to the same amount of elevation - `1dp` like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/turn_play_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/turn_btn_voice"

    android:elevation="1dp"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_24px"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

The mock app UI I coded looks fine with the elevation. The Preview Pane of the IDE or emulator may show different than the actual app UI :

[image: Don't get confused with the Preview Pane or Emulator and the real app UI]

Comment: I tried, but the ImageView still hides behind the Button, only leaves a gray border, I'll update the question to show this

Comment: I guess the display of Android Studio's preview panel would be different with what's on emulator and phone? a bit confused here.

Comment: Yes. I've created & tested a similar layout and here you can look at the screenshot directly from my device, the shadow is just a result from the Android Studio preview, it's all fine in the app if the elevation is right.

Comment: I got the desired result from app running on emulator, with elevation set to 5 (lower than 2 will hide the view behind the button).
so I guess it's just some weird setting for IDE Preview panel which confused me. on Preview panel, anything with elevation higher than 1 will be given a gray background.

Answer (score 0):

don't use elevation
use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack">
    </LinearLayout>

     <!--It will be on top of linear layout-->
    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

conclusion : Android layout order is backward. if you want to put widget A on top of widget B, just add widget A below widget B on xml

Comment: thanks, but your solution can't solve my problem, a button will have an elevation of 2 in my case, so no matter how I place the views in the layout xml, the button will always be at the top. I have to adjust the elevation of other views.

Comment: I see, the solution is nested layout, you can use contraint layout inside constraint layout,  only outer constraint layout have elevation @xmanreturn